# What are the options for extracting data out of Hyperion 7.3 with SSIS?

Tags: ssis, etl, hyperion, essbase

We need to get data out of some Hyperion cubes (databases) using SSIS. Are there any connection managers available for this? Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some third party connectors out there. Don't think any exist from oracle or microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but I just happened upon it and thought I would offer some perspective. There isn't build in support for getting data from Hyperion with SSIS. There are a few ways to go, however.

You can fairly easily export Hyperion data with a calc or report script to text/SQL. You could use SSIS to run a batch file that kicks off a Hyperion job that loads up a SQL database or text file, *then* load it with SSIS.

There are a handful of tools with Essbase adapters so you can use those if you aren't using SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Hyperion, but can you make use of the Script Task in SSIS?

Comment: This is a very old answer but just since I'm browsing around today: no, the Script Task would not be appropriate in this case. Just about the only way that SSIS can possibly talk to Hyperion would be extracting data via the technology-agnostic MDX access, and even then that would be a bit orthogonal to the row-based processing that SSIS wants to do.